# Can a gang die? If so, how?

Tags: apocalypse-world

I was reading through the Harms & Healing chapter and I started to wonder exactly how it works for gangs. The rules as written are crystal clear, but how do we handle the unmentioned specifics?

1. Can a gang die, just like a PC or NPC? The rules speak about a gang holding up, is that the same as staying alive?
2. Do we track harm like for individuals, and run around in desperation for someone willing to heal it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. A gang can "die" either by being decimated from harm or, by lack of a strong leader, failing to hold together (page 169).  If they're no longer operating as a gang, you no longer need the gang rules.  Deal with losses of both sort when trying to reform the gang, e.g., both could easily affect the size of the new gang.
2. There aren't moves for healing a whole gang, just individuals. (You could make your own custom moves for this, of course. Like, I could imagine if an Angel had a gang devoted to healing.) Harm towards gangs breaks down into harm toward members that needs to be dealt with individually.